# Loop coding in VBA

Tags: vba, loops, copy-paste

Say I only want to copy the contract number, in column A, which has "Y" in column C (column C is a flag, it's either a Y or N) and paste the number in a new tab. How can I do it?

I tried to write up something and it failed to work. =(

Thanks!

```
Sub Test()

Do

Count = 1

 On Error GoTo ErrHandler
 On Error Resume Next
If Range("CheckContract").Offset(Count, 2).Value = "Y" Then
Range("CheckContract").Offset(Count, 0).Copy
Range("PasteRange").Offset(Count, 0).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
End If

Count = Count + 1

Loop While Range("CheckContract").Offset(Count, 0).Value <> ""
Exit Sub
```

ErrHandler:

```
MsgBox Prompt:="Please check the inputs", Buttons:=vbExclamation, Title:="Error Msg"
End Sub
```

Comment: Could You please fix Your code mark-up and indentation? Also, provide output and input You can't get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim lrow As Integer
lrow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$C$" & lrow).AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="Y"
    Columns("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
    Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
    ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub
```